# How to get data from server and install in sqlite

Tags: ios, web-services, sqlite

Now I have a server with many tables. In xcode, I use sqlite to store data from 1 table of server, so what should I do to connect and get data from server to store in slite db ?

Comment: This question is too vague.  How does the server present the data?  XML, JSON, what?

Comment: List Of Question in two lines.
`1.` Create Xml/Json/WebService on Server ?
`2.` Read data through Xml/Json/WebService on client side and create Bean Class ?
`3.` Create Database/Table with Sqlite on client side ?
`4.` Use Insert Query and add data in tables.
`5.` Use Select Query and populate data in App.
`Note` Are you looking for source code ?

Comment: can you share it ? I don't know how server and sqlite connect each other !

Comment: I use php in server side !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have server side scripts ready for web services either `REST` or `SOAP` webservices.

Then, all you'll need to do in your iPhone app is use an `NSURLConnection` to fetch the URL. `NSURLConnection` is a very nice, `asynchronous` way of downloading files from remote locations.

After that, it's a simple matter of parsing the `XML` or `JSON` you can do that by using `NSXMLParser`

http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser

`NSJSONSerialization`

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

or third party api's

Once you have sorted out the required data you can save it in `sqlite` db in your device

This link should get you some idea about `sqlite`

http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-101-for-iphone-developers-making-our-app

Hope it helps :)